# A SHA-1 collision has been found. Does that mean the Monero repositories on Github can be compromised?

Tags: security, github, source, git

Git (and thus Github) relies on the SHA-1 hash function to guarantee that files can't be secretly changed. [Now a collision has been found](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/02/at-deaths-door-for-years-widely-used-sha1-function-is-now-dead/): two different files that produce the same hash. The commercial cost to create one would be around 100 BTC at the moment. Is this a problem for Monero? Could we implement a safer hash function or would we have to wait for git to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'd need to wait for git to implement stronger collision resistance. Work is underway for this: http://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2017-February/031606.html

However, Linus (original creator of git) thinks it's not that easy to exploit in git: https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/7tp2gYWQugL